# Passing an object between to activities getting null object

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to pass dataUser object from Register activity to Login activity. But dataUser in Login activity is null.

My DataUser class implements Serializable

RegisterActivity.java:

```
DataUser dataUser = new DataUser(null, null,null);

dataUser.setName(nameET.getText().toString());

dataUser.setSurname(surnameET.getText().toString());

dataUser.setEmail(emailET.getText().toString());

Bundle bundleID = new Bundle();
bundleID.putSerializable("user", dataUser);
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("bundle", bundleID);
startActivity(intent);
```

LoginActivity.java:

```
 Bundle objectUser = getIntent().getExtras();
 if (objectUser!=null){
        dataUser= (DataUser) objectUser.getSerializable("user");
        emailET.setText(dataUser.getEmail());
 }
```

When I'm debugging this is what I get in Register Activity:
[image: CodeRegisterActivity]

[image: dataUser and bundle aren't empty]

And this is the result in LoginActivity:

[image: login getSerializable]

[image: dataUser is null]

I was trying to find the solution in other similar question, but I didn't find it. Any ideas for solving this?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you use two bundles, i mean you put in intent bundle and you have your object bundle.

try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("user",dataUser);
startActivity(intent);
```

And in your second activity try this:

```
 Bundle objectUser = getIntent().getExtras();
 if (objectUser!=null){
        dataUser= (DataUser) objectUser.getSerializable("user");
        emailET.setText(dataUser.getEmail());
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call get `getIntent().getExtras();` you are getting a bundle that contains a bundle that contains your `DataUser`.

So you could either put the data user directly in the extras
`intent.putExtra("user" , (Serializable) dataUser);`

Or get the user out of the bundle

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
Bundle bundle = extras.get("bundle");
dataUser= (DataUser) bundle.getSerializable("user");
```

Comment: Oh I didn't realize of that, thaks a lot. Solved!

Comment: I'm new here and I think I can only vote for one, if you know how can I vote for more than one let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Pass your list in intent.putExtra(), for example

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext() , LoginActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("user" , (Serializable) dataUser );
startActivity(intent);
```

and for retrieve list in NextActivity

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
dataUser= (DataUser)intent.getSerializableExtra("user");
```

Comment: That's it! Simple as that. Thank you so much I don't know why I was obsessed with doing with de Bundle

Comment: If you find it helpful than marked it as right.Happy coding @Raquel

Comment: I'm new here and I think I can only vote for one, if you know how can I vote for more than one let me know!